# React Router MemoryRouter: get GET params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Can one get the GET params when using the `MemoryRouter` of `react-router-dom`? How?

Comment: Maybe you're talking about query params? if yes then you can achieve this with react -router-dom

Comment: I finally went with ```window.location.search```